# If the ledger of peer is tampered in hyperledger fabric network, how can be the previous state of ledger restored?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode, raft, tampering

My hyperledger fabric network consists of 1 orderer, 1 organization and 3 peers. I tampered ledger of first peer and then tried to do another transaction on the same peer, then the following error was thrown: 
"**Error: deliver completed with status (SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) before txid received - proposal response:** " 
But the transaction was executed and also the block was added in tampered ledger of peer. But the tampered data was not restored to previous state.

With the reference of the answer in this link - "https://intellipaat.com/community/17752/in-hyperledger-fabric-blocks-locations-and-validity-criteria", I came to know that if the tampering is done, "the state database can be dropped and rebuilt from the blockchain". So this process of dropping and rebuilding the database is done automatically by peer or we need to do it manually?

In short, if tampering is done in ledger of peer, how can be the previous state of ledger restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the state data is in doubt, you can stop peer, drop state database, and upon restart peer will rebuild state database. When peer is stopped, the command `peer node rebuild-dbs` will drop state database for you. See the [command documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/peernode.html#peer-node-rebuild-dbs).

If the blockchain ledger itself is in doubt, you will need to either replace the peer or reset the peer to genesis blocks using `peer node reset` command. See the [command documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/peernode.html#peer-node-reset).

Comment: When blockchain ledger is tampered we get the (SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) error, if chaincode is invoked. But how can we know if blockchain ledger is tampered from peer service logs?
Also how can we know if state data is in doubt?